# How to call a method twice in a row?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a code where in my class I would like to be able to call the method answer twice like `qns.answer(5).answer(7)`. But right now when I call the method answer as below, I get the error cannot find symbol.

For example:

```
Question qns = new Question("How many apples are there in the bag?")
qns ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 0.

qns.answer(12)
==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 12.

qns.answer(12).answer(4)
==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 4.

qns
qns ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 0.
```

```
class Question {
    private final String question;
    private final int correctAns;

    public Question(String question, int correctAns) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAns = correctAns
    }

    public String answer(int myAns) {
        return String.format("%s: My answer is %d.", this.question, myAns);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: My answer is 0.", this.question);
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if you could kindly give some pointers on how to get around this.

Comment: What you’re referring to is method changing. You need your answer method to return a question object

Comment: But what you ultimately want cannot be achieved since the first method will always print its output as well which means you will have two print statements and two outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Question` can have an extra field to store the answer, and you can also write a new constructor to initialise that field.

```
private final int currentAns;

public Question(String question, int correctAns, int currentAns) {
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAns = correctAns;
    this.currentAns = currentAns;
}

public Question(String question, int correctAns) {
    this(question, correctAns, 0);
}

// toString can now use currentAns!
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s: My answer is %d.", this.question, currentAns);
}
```

Then in the `answer` method, you can return a new `Question` with the specified answer as `currentAns`:

```
public Question answer(int myAns) {
    return new Question(question, correctAns, myAns);
}
```

Now you can chain multiple `ans` calls. If `toString` is called at the end of it (whether implicitly or explicitly), you can get the desired string.

Example in JShell:

```
jshell> Question qns = new Question("How many apples are there in the bag?", 1);

qns ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 0.

jshell> qns.answer(12);
$7 ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 12.

jshell> qns.answer(12).answer(4);
$8 ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 4.

jshell> qns
qns ==> How many apples are there in the bag?: My answer is 0.
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I'm able to call the answer method twice now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the multiple times the same or different methods on one object (=**chaining**), you need to return `this` in the methods.

Since, what you try to achieve is REALLY not clear, I'll suggest something:

```java
class Question {
    private final String question;
    private final int correctAns;

    private static String format(String quest, int ans) {
        return String.format("%s: My answer is %d.", quest, ans);
    }

    public Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAns = 0;
    }

    public String answer(int myAns) {
        this.correctAns = myAns;
        System.out.println("" + this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return format(this.question, this.correctAns);
    }
}
```

This way you can call answer() in a chain, because it returns the object itself (`this`).

Comment: The above implementation would change the default answer of 0 to the new answer, which is not what I want. Thank you for your response though!